# OpenCV python image washout

Tags: python, opencv, imshow

I am trying to get average merged image to show up using the following code:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

dolphin=cv2.imread('dolphin.png',0) #Also tried without the 0
bicycle=cv2.imread('bicycle.png',0)
```

[image: Bycycle - original]
[image: Dolphin - original]

The following code adds the two images and result is same as whats shown in the course. But a simple addition avg=img1+img2 doesnt work.

[image: Simple addition - washout areas]

```
sumimg=cv2.add(dolphin,bicycle)
cv2.imshow('Sum image', sumimg)
```

Two images added together without any modification - washout areas are due to addition being over 255 for that element so the value is set to 255

```
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Following code just gives me a white image. When I try to display an half intensity dolphin or cycle ...same result except for a few black dots

[image: Adding images with division by 2]

```
avgimg=cv2.add(dolphin/2,bicycle/2)
```

same result obtained by avgimg=img1/2+img2/2

```
cv2.imshow('Avg image', avgimg)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

The Udacity course shows that if you add images by division by 2 you should get this:
[image: From Udacity course - two images added after dividing by 2]

**So the question is: When I divide either of the image by 2, the matrix contains values below 255 and addition of two matrices also contains values below 255, why then is the resulting image a complete washout?**

Comment: I am not being able to upload the images I need cause I don't have 10 reputation. Whatever ... When I add two images by first dividing the matrix by 2, all I get is white washed out image.

Comment: so what is your actual problem? you dont get washout effect? or it does not show up?

Comment: @Omi: You have 10 reputation now. If you want, you can edit the question and add the images.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you wish to add both images into one (so they both appear on the resulting image), with each one of the inputs averaged, you should use the `addWeighted()` method, like this (taken from the [docs](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d0/d86/tutorial_py_image_arithmetics.html)):

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

#load your images
dolphin = cv2.imread('dolphin.png') #use 0 for grayscale
bicycle = cv2.imread('bicycle.png') 
#add them with a weight, respectively, last parameter is a scalar added 
dst = cv2.addWeighted(dolphin,0.7,bicycle,0.3,0) 

#show
cv2.imshow('Blended Image',dst)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

*Note*: As also mentioned in the previous link, it is important to notice that `numpy` and `OpenCV` addition are different, as `numpy` has a modulo operation (%) while `OpenCV` has a saturated operation (caps at a maximum), to clarify we have this extracted example from that link:

```
>>> x = np.uint8([250])
>>> y = np.uint8([10])

>>> print( cv2.add(x,y) ) # 250+10 = 260 => 255 , saturated
[[255]]
>>> print( x+y )          # 250+10 = 260 % 256 = 4 , modulo
[4]
```

Which is probably the reason why you get a white image by using the `add()` method instead (all your pixels cap at 255 and show white color).

Comment: Thanks @GrayCygnus. This is perfectly clear now as to why a simple addition doesnt work. I tried the addweighted method. It worked just as expected and shown in the Udacity course.

Comment: Great to hear that, good luck with your coding. If this answer solved your question remember to [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) it, so other users can benefit from that. Also remember to upvote if you found it useful.